# Xubuntu guest stuck in a login loop

Tags: login

My Xubuntu guest is stuck in a login loop, so far I tried solutions mentioned here: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

And clearing files to increase disk space but it still persists.

I'm not getting any GRUB menu. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

If you recently installed Chrome Remote Desktop, uninstall it with:

`sudo apt purge chrome-remote-desktop`

Comment: It talks about it here: https://jkpe.net/ubuntu-20-login-loop-chrome-remote-desktop-rdp/ if you still want to use Chrome Remote Desktop

Comment: You've posted this exact same answer to multiple questions, including long-dead ones (necromancy!) where CRD is unlikely to be the cause.  Please don't duplicate your answers many times, thanks!